# React-bootstrap tooltip not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I have a piece of code here which is supposed to display a tooltip when the user hovers over a td cell.

```
import { DropdownButton, Tooltip } from 'react-bootstrap';

...

$(e.currentTarget).parent().prev().hover(() => {
    this.showTooltip(tooltipContent);
});

...

showTooltip(tooltipContent) {
    console.log(tooltipContent);
    return (
        <Tooltip placement="top" className="in" id="tooltip-top">
            tooltipContent
        </Tooltip>
    );
}
```

The console.log is showing the right text, but the tooltip does not show, and there is no error in the console. Am I calling the component correctly? Please help!

UPDATE:

Based on 1 answer, I changed my code to this:

```
import { DropdownButton, OverlayTrigger, Tooltip } from 'react-bootstrap';

showTooltip(tooltipContent) {
    console.log(tooltipContent);
    const tooltip = <Tooltip />;
    return (
        <OverlayTrigger placement="top" overlay={tooltip}>
            <span>tooltipContent</span>
        </OverlayTrigger>
    );
}
```

The calling function is the same:

```
$(e.currentTarget).parent().prev().hover(() => {
    this.showTooltip(tooltipContent);
});
```

But I still don't see any tooltip..

Answer (score 3):

You don't actually need to write a custom method for that, react-bootstrap has that built in. Check out the documentation: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#tooltips

You will have to put a `<Tooltip/>` element as an `overlay` prop in an `OverlayTrigger`.

```
var tooltip = <Tooltip />;
// ...
<OverlayTrigger placement="left" overlay={tooltip}>
  <td>Holy guacamole!</td>
</OverlayTrigger>
```

Or, if that breaks the layout:

```
var tooltip = <Tooltip />;
// ...

<td>
  <OverlayTrigger placement="left" overlay={tooltip}>
    Holy guacamole!
  </OverlayTrigger>
</td>
```

This code will have to be in the `render()` method. What you are doing right now is you just `return` a JSX element into nowhere, that's why the tooltip doesn't show up. It's not rendered or referenced properly in the `render()` method of your component.

Comment: Updated my answer. You're trying to render something in the `showTooltip()` function, that you don't actually need.

Comment: I see. Yes, I can remove the function...That render method is the real problem here...